# Responsive Design is working, but not aligning horizontally

Tags: html, css, responsive

I made this wholse website by myself to learn better and understand what i am doing. However the boxes (Box1,Box2 etc) are not aligning in right. I want that all headlines are on the same hight, can someone point me out?

http://hasaanlatif.de/

CSS: http://hasaanlatif.de/main.css

Comment: Please include all code relevant to the question, **in the question itself** not on a third party site. You'll want to make it a [mcve]. See also [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Use position `position:relative` and then `top` or `bottom`  property of css and use -ve or +ve values to adjust to same height

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.box {
    color: black;
    margin: 2% 0 2% 0%;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0px solid black;
    width: 33.33%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

**Change your width if want add more box**

Comment: Floating it left makes the footer relative on the page and messes the footer position up